# We need vector space structure on $\mathbb{R^n}$ in order to define the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

I was watching a lecture on topology and the professor said that you don't need the vector space structure on $\mathbb{R^n}$ in order to define the standard topology for $\mathbb{R^n}$. But in the definition of the open ball (that he used to define the standard topology), he wrote something like this:

$$B_r(x):=\bigg\{y=(y_1, ...,y_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}:\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-x_i)^2}<r\bigg\}$$

But how can we perform "$(y_i-x_i)^2$" in $\mathbb{R^n}$, only using its set and topological structure? And if I need only an aditional structure other than a vector space one, what is that?

P.S.: Sorry for the broken English.

Comment: You're performing $y_i-x_i$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You do need the ring structure on the reals, but not exactly the structure of a vector space on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I could put any structure of a vector space on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and it would not change the topology as defined above.

Comment: This is the set structure. The structure of the set $\Bbb{R}^n$ is the set of ordered $n$-tuples of real numbers. You can refer to the entries in the $n$-tuple without having to define vector space structures like addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: The topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined only in terms of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (as the product topology). The topology on $\mathbb{R}$ can also be defined without any reference to the ring operations, though in that case you need to reference the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values $y_i$ and $x_i$ in the expression are both real values, i.e., defined on $\mathbb R$. Therefore, the expression $y_i - x_i$ is not an operation on the vector space $\mathbb R^n$, but an operation in the field $\mathbb R$.

This means that even if $\mathbb R^n$ is viewed only as a set (and not as a vector space), the definition of the set $B_r(x)$ in your question is still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

The standard topology can also be defined as the product topology on the $n$th power and the topology on $\Bbb R$ just by the order on it. No group structure even on the factor is needed. But if you want a *metric*, you'll probably need some formula, and hence some algebraic structure, most likely. But purely from a topological viewpoint the order (plus set-theoretic Cartesian product structure) suffice.

Comment: By "factor" are you referring to the $x_i$? I'm used to seeing those called "components".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC yes they’re also called factor spaces or projections.

Comment: Hmm, I get "projection" (e.g. $\pi_i(\vec x) = x_i$), but I've  never seen "factor" used quite that way, unless there was some sort of structural splitting / direct summing going on too. Maybe it's algebraic geometry lingo; that's a foreign language to me.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: No, he’s talking about the coordinate **spaces**, each of which is a copy of $\Bbb R$. The $i$-th component $x_i$ of an $n$-tuple $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n$ comes from the $i$-th factor in the Cartesian product $$\underbrace{\Bbb R\times\ldots\times\Bbb R}_{n\text{ factors}}\,.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - ah, thanks. I guess my brain just farted past that.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: You’re welcome.